RJSF - disable specific filed validation based on a checkbox input
I want to disable a specific field validation if N/A checkbox is true in RJSF. Likewise each field has N/A checkbox. I need to repeat the same for all. Please help here.

We can use if-else below properties key in the schema.
       if: {
          properties: {
            <dependency_field_name>: {
              const: true,
            },
          },
        },
        then: {
          required: ["<validation_field_name>"],
        }

If the dependency field is boolean and its true, we are enabling validation for a given field in required.
